# Is a definition like $ g(f(x)) = 0 $ possible?

Tags: definition, function-and-relation-composition

Is it (in any way) possible to define function $g$ like this?

$$ f(x) = x $$
$$ g(f(x)) = 0  $$

Why?

Comment: Try to make the title more descriptive if possible. It will be more useful to people outside the question to see a more detailed title.

Comment: These equations are satisfied for any function $g(y)$ such that $g(1)=0$.  So it doesn't extend our knowledge of $g$ (or $f$) to other arguments.

Comment: Also try to give more context to the problem, i don't really understand the question. Thanks

Comment: The question is simply why this is possible or why not.

Comment: Your post is ambiguous as to whether $f(x) = 1$ for *all* arguments $x$, or if $f(x)=1$ just for some particular argument $x$ (about which you have not told us more specific information).

Comment: @hardmath What if $f(x) = x$ ?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of functions that satisfy this. hardmath gives the necessary conditions for this to hold. One example is $f(x)=1$, $g(x)=e^x-e$

Comment: Okay it wasn't a good idea to define $f(x) = 1$. I've edited the question to make clear, that $f$ isn't necessarily constant. Sorry.

Comment: Go ahead with your revised Question, making the substitution $f(x)=x$.  Now what does this say about $g(x)$?